# yii2:formatting of date for display

Tags: php, datetime, yii2

I have configured a date field appointment_date as `datetime` field in mysql db.

In my model Appointment.php rules are set like this:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['appointment_date','weekdays'], 'safe'],
            [['appointment_date'], 'date','format' => 'd-M-yyyy H:m'],
```

and in web.php under component I have set

```
'formatter' => [
        'defaultTimeZone' => 'UTC',
        'timeZone' => 'Asia/Kolkata',
```

and in my view I am trying to format the date for display like this:

```
[
    Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime('appointment_date')
 ],
```

Now I am getting the error -

```
appointment_date' is not a valid date time value: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (appointment_date) at position 0 (a): The timezone could not be found in the database
Array
(
[warning_count] => 1
[warnings] => Array
(
[6] => Double timezone specification
)

[error_count] => 3
[errors] => Array
(
[0] => The timezone could not be found in the database
[11] => Unexpected character
[12] => Double timezone specification
)
```

Whereas the date stored in the database is like : 2015-01-20 11:50:00

If I am not formatting the date and simply keeping the attribute in view as 
`appointment_date` then the date is shown as `2015-01-20 11:50:00`

I want to show the date as `20-01-2015 11:50:00`

If I am using the code like this:

```
[
    'attribute'=>'appointment_date',
     'format'=>['DateTime','php:d-m-Y H:i:s']
            ],
```

I am getting the date formatted correctly.

I want to know What I am doing wrong here in using

```
Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime('appointment_date')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's just a small typo. You are passing in a string into the `asDateTime` method where it needs the value

```
Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime('appointment_date')
```

should be

```
Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime($model->appointment_date)
```

Docs: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html#asDatetime()-detail

Comment: @fl0r- your suggestion is also correct, but I need to use long code like 'attribute=>'appointment_date`, 'value'=>Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime($model->appointment_date)

Answer (score 6):

OK it is as simple as that, I need to use

```
'appoinment_date:date'
```

or

```
'appointment_date:datetime'
```

and add the format in the component formatter

```
'formatter' => [
       'defaultTimeZone' => 'UTC',
       'timeZone' => 'Asia/Kolkata',
       'dateFormat' => 'php:d-m-Y',
       'datetimeFormat'=>'php:d-M-Y H:i:s'
```

and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

My DB type of date is `date` so it is storing and giving response in **"YYYY-DD-MM"** formate.
I did this in view (index.php) without changing logic or DB Data.

initially it was

```
'date'
```

which I changed with this-

```
            [
                'attribute' => 'date',
                'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) { 
                    return date("d-m-Y", strtotime($model->date));
                },
            ],
```

It is working fine for me,
Hope it will work for few more needy.

Comment: What if we want to show like `9 Sept 2022` ?

Answer (score 0):

Put the below code under the component section in Project/config/web.php

```
'formatter' => [
   'defaultTimeZone' => 'UTC',
   'timeZone' => 'Asia/Kolkata',
   'dateFormat' => 'php:d-m-Y',
   'datetimeFormat'=>'php:d-M-Y H:i:s'
   ]
```

Where you showing date ot datetimein your grid just add this
For Date

```
'date_column_name:date'
```

For Datetime

```
'datetime_column_name:datetime'
```

That's it.It will work for your whole project where you want to change date or datetime format.